# Navigate to file without username

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I am trying to make a program that will move a file into the startup dir and run code, on windows 7 the startup folder is past c:\Users[Username] in my case I wont know that when the code is being run.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, the environment variable `USERPROFILE` points to the user folder. In python, you can use this like:

```py
import os
user_path = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
print(user_path)
```

Note that non-Windows systems usually don't have `USERPROFILE`, they use `HOME`. If you are sticking to Windows you can use `USERPROFILE`, but if you want to make your program platform-independent, you can do the following.

```py
import os
user_path = os.path.expanduser('~')
print(user_path)
```